# patreon. How to get list of creators and count of their patrons

Tags: patreon

Maybe, somebody have any suggestions, how to get list of creators then get count of patrons in each creator (and if available also get sum)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.patreon.com/#paging-through-a-list-of-pledges) you have the official Patreon API documentation where you can find all of that